# Events from shared communication channel between threads

Tags: multithreading, haskell, reactive-banana

I have a program that solves some problem and I decided I would like to monitor in a nice GUI what it does. For GUI I chose `Gtk` which means that I need to run `mainGUI` loop in a dedicated thread and the rest of my program will occupy a different thread. I thought the communication between my program and the other thread would flow in one direction using `Chan`. I further decided to use FRP for updating the GUI on notification from the worker (the original program's logic in its separate thread). So I tried writing a simple threaded example where one thread sends `IO` actions to the monitoring thread which performs the actions (displays them). Here is my attempt:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad

import Reactive.Banana
import Reactive.Banana.Frameworks

main = do
    c <- newChan

    forkIO $ do
        actuate <=< compile $ reactimate'
                            <=< changes
                            <=< fromPoll
                            $ readChan c

    forever $ do
        threadDelay 3000000
        putStrLn "sending msg"
        writeChan c $ putStrLn "receiving msg"
```

This obviously doesn't work (it only prints `sending msg`) otherwise I wouldn't be here. What am I doing wrong? Do I need a different event that times the polling? How to do it?

I expected some interleaving of copies of the texts: `sending msg` and `receiving msg`.

---

To clarify I want to move from

```
main = do
    c <- newChan

    forkIO . forever . join . readChan $ c

    forever $ do
        threadDelay 3000000
        putStrLn "sending msg"
        writeChan c $ putStrLn "receiving msg"
```

where each message in `c :: Chan (IO ())` is read in the thread explicitly (possibly blocking), to reactive handling of the messages, i.e. describing a network of events/behaviours interconnected with GUI elements and then let the thread perform GUI loop. The network would need to take care of polling values in the channel and firing events.

---

The solution I was seeking (or something like it):

```
main = do
    (msgHandler, msgFire) <- newAddHandler

    forkIO $ do
        actuate <=< compile $ do
            eMsg <- fromAddHandler msgHandler

            reactimate $ putStrLn <$> eMsg

    forever $ do
        threadDelay 3000000
        putStrLn "sending msg"
        msgFire "receiving msg"
```

Comment: This may be helpful: https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_for_multicores#Message_passing_channels

Comment: Thanks, I am more puzzled with the FRP part rather than channels though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `fromPoll` states

> The resulting Behavior will be updated on whenever the event network processes an input event.

Since there is no event, it is never updated. `fromPoll` is intented as a quick-and-dirty way to read mutable data, but not to update the network. Rather, the documentation recommends we use `fromChanges`. But since we or, because we want `Event` anyway, let's use [`newEvent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-1.1.0.0/docs/Reactive-Banana-Frameworks.html#v:newEvent), which seems quite appropriate: it allows us to create an `Event` to which we add values by calling a `Handler` (which is an alias for `a -> IO ()`).

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad

import Reactive.Banana
import Reactive.Banana.Frameworks

main = do

    c <- newChan

    network <- compile $ do
      (event, handler) <- newEvent
      liftIO $ forkIO $ forever (readChan c >>= handler)
      reactimate event

    forkIO $ actuate network

    forever $ do
        threadDelay 3000000
        putStrLn "sending msg"
        writeChan c $ putStrLn "receiving msg"
```